# Convert return conditional from c# to visual basic .net

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, return, migration

Good morning.
I have the following c# statement:

```
return user.IsInRole(PageLogin.RuoloAdmin)       ||
       user.IsInRole(PageLogin.RuoloSiteAdmin)   ||
       user.IsInRole(PageLogin.RuoloCompilatore) ||
       user.IsInRole(PageLogin.RuoloReport)      ||
       user.IsInRole(PageLogin.RuoloForum)       ||
       user.IsInRole(PageLogin.RuoloOperatoreRiepiloghi);
```

First of all, what does it mean this type of declaration?
Then, how can I transform it in a vb.net code?

Best regards.

Comment: perhaps it would be worth expanding your code snippet as it appears incomplete

Comment: It's returning a Boolean value.  PageLogin.RuoloAdmin is a static reference to a property in the PageLogin class.  user.IsInRole() is a method that returns true or false if the user is in the role specified by the parameter.  So this line of code will return true if the user is in any one (or more) of those roles.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any declaration, so there are no declarations to explain.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be checking the users role and returning a boolean. I would assume if the user object contains one of those roles that it is returning 'true'. Links below explain or operators for c# and VB.

[C# || operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

[VB OrElse operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx)

Comment: You mean C# "||" and VB "OrElse".

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I edited my answer. I'm new here so any advice/corrections are accepted with open ears and mind.